# How to count the number of occurrences of `None` in a list?

Tags: python, boolean, list-comprehension, nonetype

I'm trying to count things that are not `None`, but I want `False` and numeric zeros to be accepted too. Reversed logic: I want to count everything except what it's been explicitly declared as `None`.

## Example

Just the 5th element it's not included in the count:

```
>>> list = ['hey', 'what', 0, False, None, 14]
>>> print(magic_count(list))
5
```

I know this isn't Python normal behavior, but how can I override Python's behavior?

### What I've tried

So far I founded people suggesting that `a if a is not None else "too bad"`, but it does not work.

I've also tried `isinstance`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just use `sum` checking if each object `is not None` which will be `True` or `False` so 1 or 0.

```
lst = ['hey','what',0,False,None,14]
print(sum(x is not None for x in lst))
```

Or using `filter` with python2:

```
print(len(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst))) # py3 -> tuple(filter(lambda x: x is not None, lst))
```

With python3 there is  *`None.__ne__()`* which will only ignore None's and filter without the need for a lambda.

```
sum(1 for _ in filter(None.__ne__, lst))
```

The advantage of `sum` is it lazily evaluates an element at a time instead of creating a full list of values.

On a side note avoid using `list` as a variable name as it shadows the python `list`.

Comment: The second approach fails in Python 3 in `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi. that is because filter in python3  returns a filter object which is an iterator,  not a list. I added another way specific to py3 to filter None's.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize you could use a "list comprehension" like that. One clarification - I actually found it worked better without `print()`. Just use `sum(x is not None for x in lst)` so it returns an int not NoneType.

Answer (score 18):

Two ways:

One, with a list expression

```
len([x for x in lst if x is not None])
```

Two, count the Nones and subtract them from the length:

```
len(lst) - lst.count(None)
```

Comment: I think your first solution is the most Pythonic and should be the accepted answer

Comment: your second option should be used more. it's just faster

Comment: The second option does not work when one element of the list is e.g. a numpy array. `[np.array([1, 2, 3, None]), None, 1].count(None)` will get you `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = ['hey','what',0,False,None,14]
print sum(1 for i in lst if i != None)
```

Comment: *This* is how to count how many list elements are not equal to `None`.

Comment: The author wants to count things that are not None. In Python statements obj != None and obj is not None are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, and you're the only one who's not counting `False` as zero. (That was praise, not a correction ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Counter` from `collections`.

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', None, None]

resulted_counter = Counter(my_list) # {'foo': 2, 'bar': 1, None: 2}

resulted_counter[None] # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently released a library containing a function [`iteration_utilities.count_items`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/count_items.html) (ok, actually 3 because I also use the helpers [`is_None`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/is_None.html) and [`is_not_None`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/is_not_None.html)) for that purpose:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import count_items, is_not_None, is_None
>>> lst = ['hey', 'what', 0, False, None, 14]
>>> count_items(lst, pred=is_not_None)  # number of items that are not None
5

>>> count_items(lst, pred=is_None)      # number of items that are None
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy for large arrays

```
import numpy as np

mylist = np.array(['hey', 'what', 0, False, None, 14])
print(sum(mylist != None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make sure that only one param was send on each call. Therefore at least 2 of the variables must be None and this worked for me.

```
a_list = [param_1, param_2, param_3] 
count = a_list.count(None) 
if count < 2:
    raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure that using **the length of the list minus the number of Nones** here sould be the best option for performance and simplicity

```py
>>> list = ['hey', 'what', 0, False, None, 14]
>>> print(len(list) - list.count(None))
5
```